# Generalized Haircomb OTS vs Winternitz OTS at 256bit hash security level

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

Suppose a 256 bit hash is used (SHA2, SHA3, ...).
How does the Winternitz OTS perform at various signature sizes?

I'd want to compare to a generalized K-teeth Haircomb:

- It's signature is $K$ of these 256-bit hashes
- the public key is one hash.
- We are signing a 256-bit message digest as well
- the chain length is approximated¹ (per Whitepaper) by:
  $$X\approx2^{256/(K-1)}\times{(K-1)!}^{1/(K-1)}-K/2$$
- Key Generation performs $X\times K+1$ hashes
- Signing invocations perform $X\times(K-1)$ hashes
- Verification invocations perform $X+1$ hashes.

**Question: What are the equivalent Hash invocation counts for Winternitz OTS, as used by the SPHINCS+ standard for instance?**

Note that I'm specifically asking for the number of hash invocations used for signing, verifying and key generation.

---

¹ $X$ (for one chain) is approximated as in [this table](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJFqp2ltHIaJWKdaayy2/KNpbwVbBWEfBW8FGwRhIa2sDZbkUIoCiRnEaRqZm@hreCroKhpqaChpQlqJmnIYhQlhXwVvfyBqoB2I8yHTPNIXoCAU7BUODOEMzHQW/6IhYHYWg/NK8FCArtjY29v9/AA) (rounded numbers, inexact).

Comment: The original description of Winternitz OTS seems to be [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_21.pdf#page=10). A more recent exposition and discussion is [there](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/191.pdf#page=3). For the current SPHINCS(+) proposal, see [this](https://sphincs.org/data/sphincs+-r3.1-specification.pdf). Without the equivalent on haircomb OTS, the question is not answerable, and might be closed as such. **Please give a definition of Haircomb OTS, or a link to that**

Comment: I've seen both. I don't get it. Only thing I see that w bits are signed simultaneously. That would suggest w = 256/K. Still, I don't understand the rest of it. The question is about Winternitz OTS, why should I explain haircomb? [Update] edited. Thanks a lot. I hope it's answerable now, I'm specifically asking for ballpark performance figures by various signature sizes, thanks.

Comment: Yes that should makes the question answerable. Would you mind that I edit the question to beautify the formula into $X\approx2^{256/(K-1)}\,{(K-1)!}^{1/(K-1)}-K/2$, and replace the huge table with a link to an online program computing that?

Comment: Please do. thanks. There is no generalized haircomb paper that I'm aware of. The inventor defined haircomb OTS for K=21, [here](https://github.com/natasha-otomoski/haircomb/blob/master/WhyTheCombOfNatashaOtomoskiHas21Teeth.txt).

Comment: Haircomb may be a decent solution if what you care about is signature size ($K$) and the verification time and don't care about the public key generation or signature generation time.  If those things are also important, haircomb makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question: What are the equivalent Hash invocation counts for Winternitz OTS, as used by the SPHINCS+ standard for instance?**

Well, that at least I can answer.

For Sphincs+ (or, in general, WOTS with $w=16$), with $n=32$ (256 bit hashes), we have $x=15$ (because $w=16$ and the chain is one less than that), and $k=67$.

So, during OTS key generation, we perform $kx+1 = 1006$ hashes [1], signing is approximately [2] $(k/2)x = 503$ hashes, and verification is approximately $(k/2)x + 1 = 504$ hashes.

For Sphincs+, OTS key generation is the main cost (as we perform it quite a lot during Sphincs+ signature generation); Haircomb appears to require considerably more, and so it would not be a good fit.

[1]: Somewhat misleading; the final hash is rather more expensive, as the amount of data hashed is considerably larger.

[2]: Approximately because it depends on the weight of the value being hashed.

Comment: how do you one time sign a w=16bit number with a 2 chains of length x=15 hashes?

Comment: I get it now. You are actually signing a 128bit number. So what makes me unable then, for instance, take one of those 67 values, calculate one more hash, and claim a distinct 256bit msg m2 was what was actually signed?? I can solve that different m2 quite easily.

Comment: Furthermore there is haircomb signing 128bits with 67 teeth and 64 hashes for verification. How is the 504 hashes for verification superior then?

Comment: @HugoFranklin: actually, we're signing a 256 bit number.  As for why a forger can't advance one of the hashes, that's because of the inverse checksum (which takes up 3 of the chains); advancing one chain always requires some other chain to back up (which the forger cannot do)

Comment: @HugoFranklin: as for why WOTS is better for Sphincs+ (even though it requires more hashes during verification): the number of hashes done during verification isn't that important (as long as it is not excessive); it's the number of hashes during public key generation time that's considerably more critical in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Hulsing's 2017 WOTS+ paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/965.pdf), section 2.2, messages of $m$-bits and chains of length $w-1$ requires $\ell=\ell_1+\ell_2$ hash outputs to form a signature where
$$\ell_1=\left[\frac m{\log w}\right],\quad\ell_2=\left[\frac{\log(\ell_1(w-1))}{\log w}\right]+1$$
and logarithms are to base 2. In your notation $K$ corresponds to $\ell$, $X$ corresponds to $w-1$ and $m$ corresponds to 256.

WOTS+ signatures make most sense when $\log w$ is a power of 2 and we can tabulate the obvious range

| $\log w$ | $w-1=X$ | $\ell=K$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 128+5=133 |
| 4 | 15 | 64+3=67 |
| 8 | 255 | 32+2=42 |
| 16 | 65535 | 16+2=18 |
| 32 | 4294967295 | 8+2=10 |

The numbers in your haircomb table bear closest comparison to the two last entries. The entries for $K=18-20$ are all majorised by the WOTS+ signature with $w=2^{16}$ and the WOTS+ signature with $w=2^{32}$ is majored by the $K=10$ haircomb.

Comment: Aren't you actually signing a 128bit number (message digest)? What makes me unable to calculate one more hash if any of the say 67 hashes and claim that a different msg is what was actually signed?

Comment: Furthermore there is haircomb signing 128bits with 67 teeth and 64 hashes for verification. How is the 504 hashes for verification superior then?

Comment: I am signing a 256-bit number. The check sum of $\ell_2$ chains prevents forgery from subchains. I really do recommend that you read Hulsing's paper. The haircomb has a good verification time, but this is hugely outweighed by the issue of key generation for multi-signature constructions such as SPHINCS+.

Comment: thanks a lot, for a hobbyist like me it means a lot.